# Roundtripping 3d objects with Unity and Clara.io?

Tags: 3d, unity-game-engine

I've been looking at Clara.io for some collaborative 3D editing of game objects for a Unity game.

From what I can see FBX is about the best format to use, but I'm having some trouble retaining textures to and from Clara.io and Unity.

Anyone have any experience roundtripping between the two in such a way so as to preserve as much detail as possible like the textures aside from just the model itself?